# SVM with too many observations, any library or solution?

Tags: r, svm

In R Studio I have a database with 77,000 rows and 50 columns, I divide the observations into train and test, and the train table is left with 59,000 observations, I am making the SVM model, I am now calculating with the tune function which parameters are the best using the radial kernel, and it never runs, it is always loaded, it could be because of the number of rows I have, does anyone know of a library or solution for this?
set.seed(123)
`tune_r = tune.svm(MH7A~., data=train, kernel="radial", cost = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10), gamma = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 5)) summary(tune_r)`

Please, help me, i am student, please, help  !!!

Comment: svm training scales superlinearly with regards to the number of observations. Also ttoring the kernel matrix scales quadratically.. Thus its not feasible for large datasets. Also one other point is you are runing a grid search. This will take ages to run. You should first try to run `svm` with cross validation before tuning and measure the time taken for one combination of the hyperparameters.  Then you could have a rough idea as to how long many hours(even days) the whole process will take

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your comment. Could you provide me with the R code of what you say? Tkanks

Comment: just use `{start_time <- proc.time();svm(MH7A~., data=train, cross = 10, kernel = 'radial', cost=0.001, gamma= 0.01);time_taken<- proc.time() - start_time}` This will approximate the time taken for just one hype-combination. Check on the column `elapsed` in the `time_take` variable and see how many seconds it takes. Then you can tell how many hours it will take to run your `tune.svm`